# Flash.alert not working in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, alert, flash-message

I'm trying to have an alert pop-up when the user fails to login with the incorrect credentials. The login won't go through but the alert doesn't show up.

This is the code that I have in my view:

```
<h2>The Maintenance Functions are restricted to authorized users only.  Please login below.</h2>
<%= form_tag(dirlogin_pageout_path, :controller => "dirlogin", :action => "pageout", :method => "post") %>
<p>
    <label for="name">User ID:</label><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :userid, params[:userid] %>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
</p>

<%= submit_tag "login" %>
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
class DirloginController < ApplicationController
  def pagein
  end

  def pageout
  user = User.find_by_userid(params[:userid])
  if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
      redirect_to maintenance_maintenancenav_path
  else
    render 'pagein'
    flash.alert = "Invalid name/password combination"
  end
end
end
```

I've also tried doing `flash[:alert] = "Invalid name/password combination"` but that doesn't work as well. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flash[:notice]` instead.

```
flash[:notice] = "Invalid name/password combination"
```

And in your view you can display it with:

```
<%= flash[:notice] %>
```

Comment: So this works! But it takes 2 failed logins for the notice to show up, and sometimes the notice text is there when the page initially loads. Any fixes to that?

Comment: Place the `flash[:notice]` before your `render` statement

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Why are there double ends at the end?

Do you try this:

```
flash.alert = "Invalid name/password combination"
render 'pagein'
```

Comment: Those end's are needed. And I have tried that and it doesn't work